# Cannot change the site collection administrator - error?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, alert, user

I am trying to change the Site Collection administrator for a site collection, in Central Admin. under Site Collection Administrators.

When I select a new user from the lookup I get the "Error. An unexpected error has occurred." and it does not enter the new user into the field.

Basically I am trying to do this because the SP administrator before me set up Alerts for SP 2010 to go to his Gmail....sooo yeah. I am trying to change this account so the alerts are being sent to the Administrator rather than a Gmail. I tried simply changing the email for that user from his Gmail to the Admin email, however, when I view the site collection the email has not changed....is there a way to refresh this?

Thanks a ton!
Tudor

Comment: Did you change the email address on the user account associated with the site collection or on his user account in the user profile service?

Comment: First I tried just changing the email but that did not update in the Site Collection. So when I view the Site Collection details I cannot see the updated email. So then I am trying to just change the user account to see if that works, and that is when I get the error...

Comment: If I got to the Manage User Profiles, I don't even have that user with the Gmail password in the list of profiles..

Comment: find the actual error in 14/LOGS and it should point you to what is really going wrong

Comment: Looking up the error by correlation ID in the LOGS gives something like this "System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined." any idea? I have tried setting my browser to IE 8 standards but still getting the same error...

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I had to change to IE 8 Standards on the server not my local machine, my mistake. Thanks for the help Dave! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to comments for original post to find out the resolution.

"Nevermind, I fixed it. I had to change to IE 8 Standards on the server not my local machine, my mistake."